# SwiftUI Table scrollTo

Tags: swiftui

Does anyone know if there's a system to scroll to a row in a SwiftUI Table?
I know I can use a List/ScrollView/ScrollViewReader combination, but I'm ideally looking for something that works with `Table`.
I did try using a ScrollViewReader around a Table, but that did nothing

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table

I'm ideally looking for a method on the Table, or something like a `TableReader`

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let emailAddress: String
    let id = UUID()
}
private var people = [
    Person(givenName: "Juan", familyName: "Chavez", emailAddress: "juanchavez@icloud.com"),
    Person(givenName: "Mei", familyName: "Chen", emailAddress: "meichen@icloud.com"),
    Person(givenName: "Tom", familyName: "Clark", emailAddress: "tomclark@icloud.com"),
    Person(givenName: "Gita", familyName: "Kumar", emailAddress: "gitakumar@icloud.com")
.... 100 more....
]

var body: some View {
  ScrollViewReader { proxy
    Table(people) {
        TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
        TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
        TableColumn("E-Mail Address", value: \.emailAddress)
    }
    .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
        proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .center)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also having trouble getting this to work. Someone please help! The conversation here seems to suggest it is possible:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/723637

But I tried exactly what they said and I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Also Where is selection being used in your code?

Comment: @J.beenie Is the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to a row in a Table with ScrollViewReader, by providing a set of selected IDs or a single selected ID.

```swift
@State private var selectedPerson: Person.ID?

var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            Button {
                selectedPerson = people.randomElement()?.id
            } label: {
                Text("Scroll")
            }

            Table(people, selection: $selectedPerson) {
                TableColumn("Given Name", value: \.givenName)
                TableColumn("Family Name", value: \.familyName)
                TableColumn("E-Mail Address", value: \.emailAddress)
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedPerson) { newValue in
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've made an example to scroll randomly or whenever you tap on a row. Output:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm bizarre I tried something exactly along those line but was not able to get it to work, I am going to try again today and accept the answer if it works. Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: This solution does not seem to work on macOS? Any ideas why?

Comment: Which MacOS version you're using? `ScrollViewReader` only supports from Mac Catalyst 14.0. @J.beenie

Comment: I am on Ventura 13.2

Comment: Oh, it's not supported iOS/MacOS below 14. I think the only way is to adapt with UIKit/Cocoa.

Comment: I just tested your solution on Sonoma 14.2 and it works!! Thanks for clarifying! How would you accomplish this in Ventura?

Comment: I haven't tried on an older version, I thought it can be accomplished with old-style delegate handler, working with offSet, etc.